# How to use another gradle project like if the sources were inside the main project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I'm new to gradle so I think/hope this is a beginners question.

Lets say I've two application projects and one library project where I put things like Utils and shared Classes which I often use on both applications.

Directory structure:

```
|
|-- library
|
|-- application1
|
`-- application2
```

To be a bit more precise: One application is my "server" and the other is the "client" and the lib is the shared part between both.

Before I switched to gradle I just add this library project as a dependency to my application projects and I was able to start using the classes from there. I was able to change/extend the contents on the library project and benefit directly (live) in my application projects. If its going to deployment I've just include all theses classes from the library project directly into the JAR of my application projects.

Now in the world of gradle I could not find a solution to include these classes this way. My current understanding is that I need to deploy my library project to mavenLocal and use these library like any other 3rd-Party lib in my application projects. This is cool but way to complicated because I often need to rebuild and re-deploy my library to my mavenLocal. Even if I just add a new public static variable to a class I need to do all the way down to deploying the lib and refreshing my applications which is way to overkill.

Isn't there a simpler integration mechanism in gradle so that I'm able to "just" integrate my lib into my applications like before?

Comment: Are these projects strictly independent, say separate Git repositories, or do they live in a single repository?

Comment: They have all its own repository and thus are independent from each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your projects often change together, consider merging them into a mono-repo and take advantage of [multi module builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#multi_project_builds) which will result in a directory structure similar to

```
Root project 'multiproject'
+--- Project ':library'
+--- Project ':application1'
+--- Project ':application2'
```

Your application projects may then depend on the library module

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':library')
}
```

The official document is descent and contains elaborate user guides on this topic.

Another option Gradle offers are [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html).

> Composite builds allow you to combine builds that are usually developed independently, for instance when trying out a bug fix in a library that your application uses.

One option to formulate a composite build is to include the build of the library project in your application projects.

`settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = 'application1'

includeBuild '../library'
```

Since you added the `eclipse` tag, I can confirm composite builds are supported in Eclipse and the application projects will have project dependencies set up in the IDE. No need to go via Maven local repository.

Comment: Great! The composite build is exactly what I was looking for. Many Thanks!